# Вложенные запросы SQL

Tags: sql

У меня есть наименование в документе:
Светильник с металлическим корпусом

После обработки я получаю массив слов:

```
array ([0]=>Светильник [1]=>с [2]=>металлическим [3]=>корпусом)
```

В базе у меня присутствуют позиции:

```
Светильник с металлическим корпусом
Светильник с пластмассовым корпусом
Светильник люминесцентный  модель "СЛ-106" с плафоном и выключателем
```

Для более-менее адекватного поиска мне в голову пришла конструкция типа ужасно вложенного запроса:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT * FROM 'materials' WHERE 'title' LIKE 'Светильник%') 
        WHERE 'title' LIKE '%c%') 
    WHERE 'title' LIKE '%металлическим%') 
WHERE 'title' LIKE '%корпусом%'
```

Т.е. идея в том, что бы последовательно отсеивать варианты начиная с первого слова в строке и т.д.

Такой запрос, разумеется не рабочий, просто пытался как то донести мысль. Не подскажете как можно одним запросом подобное реализовать?

Comment: `После обработки я получаю массив слов` - поясните эту фразу. SQL в принципе не знает, что такое массив. Ну и заодно уточните, ГДЕ ИМЕННО получается этот... массив.

Comment: Уточните в вопросе структуру таблицы `materials`. Фраза "Светильник с металлическим корпусом" хранится там как одна строка в поле `title` или разбита на 4 строки таблицы? И укажите используемую СУБД (по синтаксису предполагаю что MySQL и запрос отправляется из PHP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать полнотекстовый поиск, и, соответственно, полнотекстовый индекс. Эта ваша вакханалия вложенных запросов вкупе с повсеместным использованием `LIKE` (а это довольно медленная операция, так как она просматривает все строки) убьет любой сервер, если база окажется большой или слов в запросе будет много.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Переписал систему под полнотекстовый индекс.

Comment: Не подскажете, как выполнить запрос подобного вида:

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM materials WHERE MATCH (title, preview) AGAINST ('Хомут')) WHERE MATCH (title, preview) AGAINST ('Хомут стальной')
UPD: Разобрался, забыл добавить AS

Answer (score 1):

Вы это имели в виду?

```
SELECT *
FROM 'materials'
WHERE 'title' LIKE 'Светильник%'
   and 'title' LIKE '% c %'
   and 'title' LIKE '%металлическим%'
   and 'title' LIKE '%корпусом%'
```